# how do I find an object value in a javascript array?

Tags: javascript

What I want to do is check if the "content" is in my 'basket' before I add.

I tried this, but I don't understand why it's not working:

```
function findById(source, tag, content) {
    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
      if (source[i].tag === content) {
        return source[i];
      }
    }
    throw "Couldn't find content ";
  }
```

Here is how I am using it:

```
var basket = {};
var tag = 'someTag';
var content = 'Joe';

const key = randomFunctions.generateRandomString(); // eg ekkciiuekks

// find out if the content is already in the basket...
var result = findById(basket, tag, content);
if(!result){
   // nope... so add it.
   basket[key] = {[tag]:content};
}
```

ps.  I would like to keep answer in pure javascript

***UPDATE***

I am debugging and am getting 'undefined' when I hover over length:

```
source.length
```

***ANSWER***

With a slight modification to https://stackoverflow.com/users/7668258/maciej-kocik answer, this works:

```
function findById(source, tag, content) {
    for (let key in source) {
      let property = source[key];
      if(property[tag] === content) {
        return property[tag];
      } 
    }
    return null; // moved this OUTSIDE of for loop
  }
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the source object?

Comment: maybe you'd like to use `source[i][tag]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `source.length` is undefined in your case. You're adding a new object property, not a new array item.

Try something like:

```
function findById(source, tag, content) {
  for (let key in source) {
    let property = source[key];
    if(property[tag] === content) {
      return property[tag];
    } 
    throw "Couldn't find content";
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7668258/maciej-kocik  - Was this a good question?  did it outline all of the necessary information required for you to come up with an answer?  If so, can you please up vote it?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
const hasJoe = Object.values(basket).some( x => x.content === ‘Joe’);
```

(This isn’t quite right but I’m on my phone and editing is tricky. This is the gist of it. I’ll update when I get to a real keyboard if you don’t have an answer by then.)

Comment: Okay. Same thing. Just turn it into a function: `const hasContent = (basket, content) => Object.values(basket).some( ... )`

Answer (score 0):

Use for-in loop to iterate over the objects, we cannot use the traditional for loop. Please find the logic below, i have changed it according to for-in loop.

```js
var basket = {};
var tag = 'someTag';
var content = 'Joe';

const key = randomFunctions.generateRandomString(); // eg ekkciiuekks

function findById(source, tag, content) {
  for (const property in source) {
    if (property === tag && source[property] === content) {
      return source[i];
    }
  }
  throw "Couldn't find content ";
}

// find out if the content is already in the basket...
var result = findById(basket, tag, content);
if (!result) {
  // nope... so add it.
  basket[key] = {
    [tag]: content
  };
}
```